# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function, Slick Carousel on local machine

Tags: html, slick.js

I have followed all the tutorials I could find but I can't get it to display a simple carousel. The console says

> "Uncaught TypeError: `$(...).slick` is not a function".

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>T_T</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="testing">
            <div>Content 1</div>
            <div>Content 2</div>
        </div>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.testing').slick({
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 2000,
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me what am I missing?

It seems to work just fine in the code snippet, but when I launch it locally on my computer it doesn't work :(

Comment: Why does it work here but not if I launch the website locally on my browser????

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This really doesn't answer the question, but you can remove the `type="text/javascript"` from the `script` tags. That attribute is essentially deprecated since HTML5 was adopted. For your local issue, try adding the `https://` to the slick URL. On your local machine, it may be trying to look in *your* file directory.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was breaking my head over this. Now it works!

Comment: I'll write it as an answer, as this may help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the `src` for the carousel script is "looking" on your local machine (or may not know where to "look") since the URL Protocol (http/s:) is not defined.

`//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js`

Add the `https:` to the start of the URL.

`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js`